# Linking a domain name with posterous.com

Tags: posterous

I have recently bought a domain name through my web hosts and would like to link it to a Posterous account.

Following the instructions on the Posterous website I have entered my domain details in but all this seems to do is forward myName.posterous.com to myURL.com

Surely I need to set the nameserver details on my domain to point to the Posterous servers but I can't see anything on their site about it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gah, found it!

http://posterous.com/help/custom_domain#technical_details

Need to point the A record for my domain to 66.216.125.32

Comment: Good on you for coming back and providing the answer.